# Select elements that are not a part of an integer list in base Julia

Tags: vector, julia, element

If I have a Float64 vector Y and an integer vector x, for instance x=rand(1:1000, 500), is there an elegant way to pull the elements of Y at non-x entries? So far I have tried `Y[findall([i ∉ x for i in 1:1000])]`. This works, but coming from R, I was hoping to do something like `Y[.!x]` or `Y[!x]`, which both throw errors. I would like to refrain from a package like DataFrames, but if this is not possible I understand.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question explicitly asked for a solution that does not rely on packages outside of the standard library here is an alternative to [Przemyslaw Szufel's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67153795/15281224):

```
Y[∉(x).(1:length(Y))]
```

Here we use the partially applied form of `∉`. From the documentation for `in`:

> `in(collection)`
> `∈(collection)`
>
> Create a function that checks whether its argument is `in collection`,
> i.e. a function equivalent to `y -> y in collection`.

The same thing can be written in a few different ways, e.g. `Y[eachindex(Y) .∉ Ref(x)]` (works for this case but you should understand [`eachindex`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.eachindex) and have a look at [`LinearIndices`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.LinearIndices) and [`CartesianIndices`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.IteratorsMD.CartesianIndices)).

An important thing to note is that these solutions do not perform well when `x` is large. To improve performance a [`Set`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.Set) can be created from `x`. Example:

```
Y[∉(Set(x)).(eachindex(Y))]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `Not` from `InvertedIndices` (this also gets imported with `DataFrames`).
In your case this is `Y[Not(x)]`, see the code below:

```
julia> using InvertedIndices  # or using DataFrames

julia> Y  = collect(1:0.5:4)             
7-element Vector{Float64}:               
 1.0                                     
 1.5                                     
 2.0                                     
 2.5                                     
 3.0                                     
 3.5                                     
 4.0                                     
                                         
julia> x=rand(1:7, 3)                    
3-element Vector{Int64}:                 
 3                                       
 2                                       
 6                                       
                                         
                       
julia> Y[Not(x)]                         
4-element Vector{Float64}:               
 1.0                                     
 2.5                                     
 3.0                                     
 4.0
```